# PHP Oauth get Access Token from $_GET['code']

Tags: php, oauth

I am new to php and OAuth. It is success for login and redirect with code. And also can get access token by this .

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $code = $_GET['code'];
    $url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
    $params = array(
        "code" => $code,
        "client_id" => '123456789-123456789.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        "client_secret" => '4tyajnbsd_fgjkhlkitu',
        "redirect_uri" => 'https://example.com/loader/land.php',
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code"
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, constant("CURLOPT_" . 'URL'), $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, constant("CURLOPT_" . 'POST'), true);
    curl_setopt($ch, constant("CURLOPT_" . 'POSTFIELDS'), $params);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);   
    echo $output['access_token']; // not working to output only access token
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

}
```

It results as in picture .[image: result from the code]

But I am very new to OAuth and can't able to have access token only by

```
echo $output['access_token'];
```

And also php die after that output and can't continue to my existing code. It is very difficult to find out for me. I am just a beginner. Please help me to continue. I need to get access_token for other remaining processes. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: var_dump($output) ?

Comment: @AZinkey, it returning "bool(true)". How to continue by it please ?

Comment: Is this whole code in a function? Because there's a `return` but actually I can't see any function definition.

Comment: @Twinfriends, Hi, I copied that code from SO, can it be the main cause ? Please could you fixed for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output seems to be JSON formatted. To access the value you'll have to [`json_decode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the `$output` variable before accessing one of its values.

Just like this:

```
echo json_decode($output, true)['access_token'];
```

**Edit:**
You'll also need to add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` to get the actual result from the webpage you're trying to cURL. See [`curl_exec()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) for more information:

> Returns **TRUE** on success or **FALSE** on failure. However, if the **CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER** option is set, ***it will return the result on success***, **FALSE** on failure.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me  :)